# SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail

I know there are a lot of question regarding the same thing on SO, but I don't seem to have found the solution for my problem yet.

I am using JavaMail API to connect to a mail server. Initially I used the port 110 to connect to pop3 server and that is when I got the following exception -
`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`

I changed the port to 995 and got the following exception -

`sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

**Code for connecting to the server**:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
store           = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect(ServerName, Port, UserName, Password);
```

Where am I going wrong? Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error message says it all. You're attempting SSL to a plaintext port. Try disabling SSL, or use the correct port for SSL.

The second one says that your truststore doesn't trust the server certificate. If it's self-signed, you will need to import it into your truststore.

Comment: For the first exception - I've tried both 110 and 995. Didn't work for either of them.

Comment: Yes it did. When you used port 995 you got past the first problem to the second problem. That's progress. You can't get an SSL certificate exception unless the peer is speaking SSL.

Comment: The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) will help.